# ATP cost for gene expression

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, metabolism

How would you estimate the number of ATPs required to transcribe, export and translate a single eukariotic protein?

Comment: Is this in bacterial or human? Transcribing a pre-mRNA and splicing are significant contributors to this energy cost calculation. Don't forget charging of tRNAs with amino acids.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question: I was thinking about eukariotes.

Comment: I'm assuming this wouldn't take into account the ATP cost of transcribing / translating / regulating any of the proteins required for transcription / export / translation?

Comment: @GWW, No: I assume the cell contains already all the required machinery.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cost of transcribing and translating a hypothetical average gene in yeast has been calculated as 551 activated phosphate bonds ~P per second ([Wagner, 2005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msi126)).

> The median length of a yeast RNA molecule is 1,474 nucleotides, and
>   the median cost of precursor synthesis per nucleotide (derived from
>   the base composition of yeast-coding regions) is 49.3 ∼P. With a
>   median mRNA abundance of R = 1.2 mRNA molecules per cell and a median
>   mRNA decay constant of dR = 5.6 × 10−4 s−1, the mRNA synthesis costs
>   calculates as 49.3 × 1,474 × 1.2 × (5.6 × 10−4) = 48.8 ∼P per second
>   and cell. This is a fraction 48.8/1.34 × 107 = 3.6 × 10−6 of the total
>   RNA synthesis cost per second. The median length of a yeast protein is
>   385 amino acids, with a combined biosynthesis and polymerization cost
>   of 30.3 ∼P per amino acid. The median abundance is 2,460 protein
>   molecules per cell. No currently available data allows a meaningful
>   estimate of the median protein half-life, but a protein of an
>   intermediate half-life (see below) of 10 h (decay constant dP = 1.92 ×
>   10−5 s−1) yields an overall synthesis cost of 30.3 × 385 × 2,460 ×
>   (1.92 × 10−5) = 551 ∼P s−1.

For your question about a single gene, the cost would be 49.3 * 1474 ~P for the mRNA and 30.3 * 385 ~P for the translation, which would result in around 84 thousand ~P. This is probably a very misleading statistic as you can transcribe multiple proteins from a single mRNA.

How the cost of mRNA synthesis and translation are calculated is described in detail in the paper. A large part of the cost comes from the synthesis of the basic building blocks, the nucleotides and the amino acids.

---

- [Wagner, A. Energy Constraints on the Evolution of Gene Expression. *Mol Biol Evol* **22**, 1365-1374 (2005).](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msi126)